# Update Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

Postgres sql don't recognize the B relation.

Anyone knows how to make this query work?

```
UPDATE B SET fator = A.fator
FROM 
(select initial_date, end_date,entity_id, sum(fator) fator
                                from table1 
                                    where initial_date>=(select min(data) from iberia.lcs_wyipi_aux_produtividade_incentivos)
                                                and end_date<=(select max(data) from iberia.lcs_wyipi_aux_produtividade_incentivos)
                            GROUP BY initial_date, end_date, entity_id) A JOIN table2 B on
                                                     A.entity_id=B.entity_id and B.data>=A.initial_date and B.data<=A.end_date
```

> [Err] ERROR:  relation "b" does not exist
>   LINE 1: UPDATE B SET fator = A.fator

Comment: Is the table named `b` or `"B"`? i.e. is it upper-case? check in a table listing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating `table2`, you don't need to join the "from" table to it. Also, the alias `B` should be set when the table is mentioned right after the `UPDATE` keyword.

```
UPDATE table2 as B SET fator = A.fator
FROM (
    select initial_date, end_date,entity_id, sum(fator) fator from table1 
    where initial_date >= ( select min(data) from iberia.lcs_wyipi_aux_produtividade_incentivos )
      and end_date <= ( select max(data) from iberia.lcs_wyipi_aux_produtividade_incentivos )
    GROUP BY initial_date, end_date, entity_id
) as A
where B.entity_id = A.entity_id
  and B.data >= A.initial_date
  and B.data <= A.end_date
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but I think if you wrap your source in a subquery, it will do what you seek:

```
with A as (
  select
    initial_date, end_date, entity_id, sum(fator) fator
  from table1 
  where
     initial_date >= (select min(data)
                      from iberia.lcs_wyipi_aux_produtividade_incentivos) and
     end_date <= (select max(data)
                  from iberia.lcs_wyipi_aux_produtividade_incentivos)
   GROUP BY initial_date, end_date, entity_id
)
UPDATE table2 B
SET fator = A.fator
FROM 
  A
where
  A.entity_id = B.entity_id and
  B.data between A.initial_date and A.end_date
```

By only concern is that based on the criteria you described, it *seems* possible that the subquery that is joined could yield more than one value you are trying to update in `table`.  If that's not the case, this should work.  If it is, you need some way to narrow down which record you want to update.